# Showing items orderly as ordered in mysql table

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by

I have two tables in MySQL : `category` and `items`. 
The `items` table has a filed `category` which matches the `category` table name.

I have used INNER JOIN statement:

```
<?php 
$sql = 'SELECT 
            category.category_name AS cat, 
            items.name AS name, 
            items.prices AS prices 
        FROM 
            category 
        INNER JOIN items ON 
            items.category=category.id 
        ORDER BY 
            category.id ASC';
```

And the tables are:

```
-- `items` table: 

id  name                     prices  category
1   1/4 Peri Peri chicken    0.5     1
2   1/2 Peri Peri Chicken    4.95    1
3   Whole Peri Peri Chicken  9.75    1
4   6 Chicken Strips         3.99    1


-- `category` table:

id  category_name
1   PERI PERI CHICKEN
```

I want to show the items in the same order they are in the MySQL table, but they are showing differently.

Answer (score 0):

Then order by `items.id`:

```
ORDER BY items.id ASC
```

However, you might want the ordering *within* each category:

```
ORDER BY category.id, items.id ASC
```